# Missing "Create Attribute Group" button

Tags: marketing-cloud, contactbuilder, data-designer

I'm following step 1 here: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_cab_create_an_attribute_group.htm&type=5

There is no "create Attribute Group" button.

How do I create an attribute group? I can request missing accesses, but my roles are currently Admin, Marketing Cloud Admin, and several other Marketing Cloud roles (Content creator, etc).

[image: Data Designer]
[image: Right panel of Data Designer]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of those other roles are denying you the correct permission. You should remove all roles except admin and Mc admin